# geopandas choropleth: Dataframe object has no attribute "total_bounds"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I keep getting this error whenever I try to plot a choropleth:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [337], in <cell line: 15>()
     13 scheme =mc.EqualInterval(pro['total'], k=10)# mc.UserDefined(reach_map['reach_equivalent'], bins=[0,10,20,30,40,50,60])
     14  #Map
---> 15 gplt.choropleth(pro, 
     16     hue="total", 
     17     linewidth=.2,
     18      cmap='inferno_r',
     19     scheme=scheme,
     20     legend=True,
     21     edgecolor='black',
     22     ax=ax
     23 );
     24 ax.set_title('CAD CDC hospitalization', fontsize=13)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\geoplot\geoplot.py:995, in choropleth(df, projection, hue, cmap, norm, scheme, legend, legend_kwargs, legend_labels, legend_values, extent, figsize, ax, **kwargs)
    991                     ax.add_patch(feature)
    993         return ax
--> 995 plot = ChoroplethPlot(
    996     df, figsize=figsize, ax=ax, extent=extent, projection=projection,
    997     hue=hue, scheme=scheme, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
    998     legend=legend, legend_values=legend_values, legend_labels=legend_labels,
    999     legend_kwargs=legend_kwargs, **kwargs
   1000 )
   1001 return plot.draw()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\geoplot\geoplot.py:965, in choropleth.<locals>.ChoroplethPlot.__init__(self, df, **kwargs)
    964 def __init__(self, df, **kwargs):
--> 965     super().__init__(df, **kwargs)
    966     self.set_hue_values(color_kwarg=None, default_color=None)
    967     self.paint_legend(supports_hue=True, supports_scale=False)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\geoplot\geoplot.py:628, in Plot.__init__(self, df, **kwargs)
    626 self.projection = kwargs.pop('projection')
    627 # TODO: init_axes() -> init_axes(ax)
--> 628 self.init_axes()
    629 self.kwargs = kwargs

File ~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\geoplot\geoplot.py:639, in Plot.init_axes(self)
    637     extrema = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])  # default Matplotlib plot extent
    638 else:
--> 639     xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = self.df.total_bounds
    640     # Plots suffer clipping issues if we use just the geometry extrema due to plot features
    641     # that fall outside of the viewport. The most common case is the edges of polygon
    642     # patches with non-zero linewidth. We partially ameliorate the problem by increasing
   (...)
    645     # degrees varies depending on where you are on the globe. Since the effect is small we
    646     # ignore this problem here, for simplicity's sake.
    647     extrema = relax_bounds(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:5575, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5568 if (
   5569     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5570     and name not in self._metadata
   5571     and name not in self._accessors
   5572     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5573 ):
   5574     return self[name]
-> 5575 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'total_bounds'
```

This is my code

```
import mapclassify as mc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import geoplot as gplt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import pandas as pd
import pprint as pp
import seaborn as sns
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 10))
scheme =mc.EqualInterval(pro['total'], k=10)
 #Map
gplt.choropleth(pro, 
    hue="total", 
    linewidth=.2,
     cmap='inferno_r',
    scheme=scheme,
    legend=True,
    edgecolor='black',
    ax=ax
);
ax.set_title('CAD CDC hospitalization', fontsize=13)
```

Can anyone help me out with this? I'm not entirely sure where the error is coming from or what is causing it,I've tried manipulating each of the types of the data that I want to plot but it doesn't help much. I tried checking if there is an issue with the type of the geometry used to plot but thats not helping either.

Comment: `pro` is likely not a `GeoDataFrame` and just a plain `DataFrame`.

Comment: but I initially loaded it as a dataframe and performed a few merges on it, is there anyway to make it into a geodataframe?

Comment: sorry I initially loaded it as a Geodataframe and performed merges on it.

Comment: can you show us your code? it's hard to help without knowing what we're working with. is there a `geometry` column in `pro`? If so, you can just initialize a geodataframe with `pro = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pro)` - see https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html